# Unable to send Emails to university email addresses

Tags: email, spf, dkim, blacklist, dmarc

I use dnsimple to host my DNS and have valid SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records to validate my emails sent from Zoho. However, Whenever I send emails to an @ucdavis.edu account I get an Undelivered Mail response

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software. 
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. 

lsmiyashita@ucdavis.edu, ERROR_CODE :550, ERROR_CODE :5.7.1 <admin@study.space>... Access denied 



Received:from mail.zoho.com by mx.zohomail.com 
    with SMTP id 1478675695600485.6815385213283; Tue, 8 Nov 2016 23:14:55 -0800 (PST) 
Message-ID:<15847f087ed.112901d8e106580.9166398699723335101@study.space> 
Date:Tue, 08 Nov 2016 23:14:55 -0800 
From:Jacob Bevilacqua <admin@study.space> 
User-Agent:Zoho Mail 
To:"lsmiyashita" <lsmiyashita@ucdavis.edu> 
Subject:Here's a little test for you. 
Content-Type:multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_335760_1020694757.1478675695597"
```

I have tried several different hosts (GSuite, MailGun, & Zoho) and I get the same issue. I checked and I am not blacklisted on any sites. I ran a test at mail-tester.com and got a 10/10. Why won't my messages deliver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I verified that the email address you are sending to is valid: [Verified Email Address](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/emailvalidator/lsmiyashita@ucdavis.edu/)

So like @Synchro says, they just don't like you. It's always a challenge to figure out the exact reason, but contacting their admins is the right way to go. I have a feeling it's because of the .space domain ending, they probably haven't updated the list of domain endings they accept.

Anyway, if you wanted to do additional mail testing, use this [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/).

Answer (score 1):

You are under the unfortunate illusion that it's your fault. A 5.7.1 error means that they just don't like you, and they don't have to give a reason. Welcome to the world of deliverability, or lack thereof. Well-behaved mailers are often punished for no particular reason. If it's just this domain, your best bet might be to contact their admins.